# How to update a checkboxGroupInput based on the levels of a column?

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have create one app that allows to subset a dataframe based on a `checkboxGroupInput` and `radioButtons`.

[image]

[image]

The function of`radioButtons` basically is remove the samples categorized as "excluded" or not.

Here is my code.

```
    #data
       #data
df <- structure(list(Val1 = c(71L, 19L, 13L, 73L, 30L, 6L, 89L, 39L, 
                              64L, 33L, 47L, 54L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 94L, 77L, 34L, 25L, 52L, 37L, 
                              87L, 32L, 14L, 62L, 20L, 38L, 27L, 85L, 90L, 28L, 29L, 40L, 41L, 
                              83L, 4L, 57L, 61L, 72L, 95L, 21L, 65L, 98L, 97L, 2L, 100L, 50L, 
                              59L, 46L, 45L), Val2 = c(27L, 31L, 2L, 29L, 46L, 12L, 6L, 26L, 
                                                       28L, 35L, 1L, 24L, 20L, 18L, 11L, 39L, 17L, 36L, 40L, 5L, 14L, 
                                                       43L, 10L, 15L, 34L, 48L, 3L, 22L, 44L, 45L, 30L, 33L, 32L, 49L, 
                                                       47L, 23L, 7L, 19L, 13L, 41L, 16L, 4L, 37L, 38L, 50L, 42L, 21L, 
                                                       8L, 9L, 25L), AfterExclusion = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                  4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                  2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
                                                                                                  2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("b", 
                                                                                                                                                                  "c", "d", "excluded_sample"), class = "factor"), BeforeExclusion = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1L), levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -50L), class = "data.frame")

library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput("choose_variables", "Variables to select:", value=TRUE),
    
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.choose_variables",
      style = "margin-left: 20px;",
      
      checkboxGroupInput("selection", "",
                         c("Excluded" = "excluded_sample",
                           "b" = "b",
                           "c" = "c",
                           "d" = "d"),
                         selected = c("excluded_sample", "b", "c", "d"))),
    hr(),
    
    checkboxInput(inputId = "criteria", label = "Choose criteria"),
    conditionalPanel(
      
      condition = "input.criteria == '1'",
      style = "margin-left: 20px;",
      radioButtons(inputId = "exclusion_criteria_samples", label="", 
                   c("Remove excluded samples" = "remove_excluded_samples", 
                     "Without any exclusion criteria" = "all_samples"))),
    
    actionButton("Submit", "Submit")
    
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mydata <- reactive({
    data <- df
    
    if(input$choose_variables){
      data <- data %>%
        filter(AfterExclusion %in% c(input$selection)) %>%
        droplevels() # we update the current levels
    }
    
    
    if(input$criteria){
      if(input$exclusion_criteria_samples == "all_samples"){
        data$AfterExclusion <- NULL
        names(data)[names(data) == "BeforeExclusion"] <- "Col" # change name of the column
        
      }else{
        data <- subset(data, data$AfterExclusion != "excluded_sample")
        data <- data %>% droplevels()
        data$BeforeExclusion <- NULL
        names(data)[names(data) == "AfterExclusion"] <- "Col" # change name of the column
        
      }
    }else{
      data <- data
    }
    
    return(data)
    
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$Submit)
  
  
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$choose_variables)
    mydata()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The idea is that if the user clicks "Choose criteria" and "Remove excluded samples", I would like to update the `checkboxGroupInput` with the new levels of the dataframe. However, if after doing that, the user wants to select "Without any exclusion criteria" I would like the original `checkboxGroupInput` (with all the original levels).

I managed to get something close based on an `actionButton` but once I have selected "Remove excluded samples" and I get the updated `checkboxGroupInput`, **I cannot go back to the original one if I select the other option.**

(see the code that I have added just before `renderDataTable` in order to do this)

[image]

```
 observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    
    if(input$criteria){
      list_variables <- levels(mydata()$Col)
      
      
      if(input$exclusion_criteria_samples == "all_samples"){
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "selection",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = list_variables,
                                 selected = list_variables)
        print(list_variables)
      }
      else if(input$exclusion_criteria_samples == "remove_excluded_samples"){
        print(list_variables)
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "selection",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = list_variables,
                                 selected = list_variables)
      }
    }
  })
```

Does anybody know how to help me?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
selected_all <- c("excluded_sample", "b", "c", "d")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput("choose_variables", "Variables to select:", value=TRUE),
    
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.choose_variables",
      style = "margin-left: 20px;",
      
      checkboxGroupInput("selection", "",
                         c("Excluded" = "excluded_sample",
                           "b" = "b",
                           "c" = "c",
                           "d" = "d"),
                         selected = selected_all )),
    hr(),
    
    checkboxInput(inputId = "criteria", label = "Choose criteria"),
    conditionalPanel(
      
      condition = "input.criteria == '1'",
      style = "margin-left: 20px;",
      radioButtons(inputId = "exclusion_criteria_samples", label="", 
                   c("Remove excluded samples" = "remove_excluded_samples", 
                     "Without any exclusion criteria" = "all_samples"))),
    
    actionButton("Submit", "Submit")
    
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mydata <- reactive({
    data <- df
    
    if(input$choose_variables){
      data <- data %>%
        filter(AfterExclusion %in% c(input$selection)) %>%
        droplevels() # we update the current levels
    }
    
    
    if(input$criteria){
      if(input$exclusion_criteria_samples == "all_samples"){
        data$AfterExclusion <- NULL
        names(data)[names(data) == "BeforeExclusion"] <- "Col" # change name of the column
        
      }else{
        data <- subset(data, data$AfterExclusion != "excluded_sample")
        data <- data %>% droplevels()
        data$BeforeExclusion <- NULL
        names(data)[names(data) == "AfterExclusion"] <- "Col" # change name of the column
        
      }
    }else{
      data <- data
    }
    
    return(data)
    
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$Submit)
  
  observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    
    if(input$criteria){
      list_variables <- levels(mydata()$Col)
      
      
      if(input$exclusion_criteria_samples == "all_samples"){
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "selection",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = selected_all,
                                 selected = selected_all)
        print(list_variables)
      }
      else if(input$exclusion_criteria_samples == "remove_excluded_samples"){
        print(list_variables)
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "selection",
                                 label = "",
                                 choices = list_variables,
                                 selected = list_variables)
      }
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$choose_variables)
    mydata()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! It works but... when I have selected "remove excluded samples" + submit (the `checkboxGroupInput` updates) and then I select "without any exclusion criteria" + submit and the `checkboxGroupInput` also updates, I have to click the submit button a second time to get the table updated. Do you know if there is another way to avoid clicking 2 times and update the `checkboxGroupInput` and the table at the same time?

Comment: That is due to `%>% bindEvent(input$Submit)` while creating `mydata`.  If you comment that out, there is an immediate reactivity.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to keep the `actionButton` and control all the changes with it... Thanks very much again!

Comment: I have another option that could be valid, instead of using `observeEvent`, it is possible to use  `observe({ req(input$criteria) })`. With this, the `checkboxGroupInput` updates and you only have to click once.